# How to solve "Uncaught exception 'google\net\ProtocolBufferEncodeError'"

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine in combination with PHP.

After a couple request I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\net\ProtocolBufferEncodeError' with message 'Internal bug: Encoded size doesn't match predicted' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php:68
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php(50): google\net\ProtocolMessage->serializePartialToString()
#1 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php(52): google\net\ProtocolMessage->serializeToString()
#2 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php(42): google\appengine\runtime\RealApiProxy->makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse), NULL)
#3 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushQueue.php(195): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php on line 68

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\net\ProtocolBufferEncodeError' with message 'Internal bug: Encoded size doesn't match predicted' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php:68
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php(50): google\net\ProtocolMessage->serializePartialToString()
#1 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php(52): google\net\ProtocolMessage->serializeToString()
#2 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php(42): google\appengine\runtime\RealApiProxy->makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse), NULL)
#3 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushQueue.php(195): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('taskqueue', 'BulkAdd', Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddRequest), Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueBulkAddResponse in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php on line 68
```

To solve this I shutdown all the instances and the code just loads normally. And again after a couple of request I get the same fatal error.

What can cause this Fatal error ? And how do I solve it.

---

The error is raised in the following file
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/4523f63814037ed833b8bb55273c09a43dd69fb0/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/proto/ProtocolMessage.php

Comment: What are you trying to put into the taskqueue ?

Comment: Tasks which include MySql queries in arguments. I removed this line, and now the error is not showing up anymore.

Comment: Show us what you are actually passing in. The protocol buffers are having trouble encoding things.  I have no knowledge of PHP, however it might be worth changing your code to use some arguments/params that allow you to construct the query in PHP rather than trying to pass in a query definition.

Comment: Array
    (
        [connection_id] => 4
        [user_id] => 3
        [db_name] => tms_global
        [query] => UPDATE `users` SET `last_alive` = &#039;2013-11-12 15:04:17&#039; WHERE `id` = 3 LIMIT 1
        [log_url] => http://localhost:8080/
     )